# color change for the loading bar component of material ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to learn material ui.
- I am trying to change the css of the loading bar.
- I referred to the documentation and used colorPrimary classes
- but its not changing.
- can you tell me how to fix it so taht in future I will fix it myself
- providing my code snippet below.
- all my code is in ReceipeReviewCardList.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/2zonj08v5r

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  colorPrimary: {
    color: "green"
  }
};


 render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <LinearProgress
          className={classes.colorPrimary}
          variant="determinate"
          value={this.state.completed}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you set the CSS is not correctly,

```
    const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  colorPrimary: {
    background: 'green'
  }
};
```

not:

```
    const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  colorPrimary: {
    color: "green",
  }
};
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 12):

you can use example as was in the reply of the `issue` in `material ui` `github` project: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12858#issuecomment-421150158

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { LinearProgress } from '@material-ui/core';

class ColoredLinearProgress extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return <LinearProgress {...this.props} classes={{colorPrimary: classes.colorPrimary, barColorPrimary: classes.barColorPrimary}}/>;
  }
}

const styles = props => ({
  colorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: '#00695C',
  },
  barColorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: '#B2DFDB',
  }
});

export default  withStyles(styles)(ColoredLinearProgress);
```

It works perfect.

Answer (score 9):

For Material UI v5 (@mui)

```
<LinearProgress sx={{
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  '& .MuiLinearProgress-bar': {
                    backgroundColor: 'green'
                  }
                }}
                variant="determinate"
                value={10}/>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can override the background colors with makeStyles.

On makeStyles file:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    root: {
        "& .MuiLinearProgress-colorPrimary": {
            backgroundColor: "red",
        },
        "& .MuiLinearProgress-barColorPrimary": {
            backgroundColor: "green",
        },
    },
})
```

Import and use:

```
import { useStyles } from "./myFile.style";
...
const classes = useStyles();
...
<div className={classes.root}>
    <LinearProgress />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy workaround i stumbled upon which doesn't seem too much of a hack:

```
<LinearProgress
      className="VolumeBar"
      variant="determinate"
      value={volume}
    />
.VolumeBar > * { background-color:green; }
.VolumeBar{background-color:gray ;}
```

The first rule makes the progress appear green(completed part).
The second rule takes care of the uncompleted part .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overwrite with sx:

```
 sx={{
                    '& .MuiLinearProgress-bar1Determinate': {
                        backgroundColor: 'red',
                    }
}}
```

the color of the main bar is set as the BACKGROUNDCOLOR, NOT the COLOR

Answer (score 1):

I did do it by this way, creating your own theme

```
     import {createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
        
           
           const theme = createMuiTheme({
              palette: {
                 secondary: {
                     main: '#42baf5'
                 }
              }
            })
     

          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <LinearProgress color="secondary"/> 
          </MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const BorderLinearProgress = withStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
        width: '95%',
        height: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginTop: 8,
        marginBottom: 20
    },
    colorPrimary: {
        backgroundColor: Liquidity.colors.main.pink,
    },
    bar: {
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: Liquidity.colors.main.yellow,
    },
  }),
)(LinearProgress);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Material ui version 4):

```
progressbar: {
  background: 'yellow',

  '& .MuiLinearProgress-bar': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.main,
  },
},
```

And then

```
<LinearProgress
            className={classes.progressbar}
            variant="determinate"
            value={30}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That have worked for me !
First set a className to the `LinearProgress` component

```
<LinearProgress
    className="custom-class"
    variant="determinate"
    value={MyValue}
/>
```

then style it from your attached css file as shown in the following :

```
.custom-class > * { background-color:green !important; }
.custom-class{background-color:gray !important;}
```

using the `!important` tag is premordial to override the original color.

Comment: For anyone learning, you really want to avoid using `!important` as much as possible, ideally not using it at all. MUI exposes a CSS class structure you can access to modify the styles of any component without having to incur in using `!important`. 

If that weren't the case, you can still use [CSS specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) to override a class -- which is why you don't want to use "!important" in the first place, because it messes up with the specificity.

Answer (score 0):

- style:  `progress: { color: 'red' },`
- Component:
  `<LinearProgress color="inherit" className={classes.progress} />`